# Usar set com Scanner e array

Tags: java

Estou com a seguinte dúvida: 
estou usando o seguinte código que funciona tranquilamente

```
System.out.println("Digite a Primeira Nota: ");

Scanner inNota1 = new Scanner(System.in);

 estud.notas[0] = inNota1.nextDouble();
```

Mas ao aprender sobre o método private e  set não sei como construir o código. Ficaria algo parecido com isso??

```
System.out.println("Digite a Primeira Nota: ");
        Scanner inNota1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        estud.setNotas[0](inNota1.nextDouble());
```

Como especifiquei, quando uso em método publico consigo usar o primeiro código com o Scanner tranquilamente, agora usando o método private não sei como atribuir a posição da memória do array e nem como inserir a variável do Scanner na sintaxe do set

Comment: Não, não ficaria isso. Não chegaria nem perto disso. Para podermos responder essa pergunta, explique quais são as suas classes e como elas se relacionam. Suas classes são `Estudante` e `Nota`? Por sinal, se notas é um array, provavelmente usar um setter não vai ser o melhor caminho.

Answer (score 1):

`private` e *set* são conceitos distintos:

---

**`private`**

A *keyword* `private` é o que chamamos de *Modificador de Acesso*.
Existem, basicamente, três modificadores de acesso: `public`, `protected` e `private`:

- `public`: este é o modificador de acesso mais "aberto" que existe no Java. Qualquer classe pode acessar o membro que possui este modificador de acesso. Não precisa ser uma classe filha da classe que possui membros com esse modificador de acesso (também conhecidos como *membros públicos*) nem estar no mesmo pacote;
- `protected`: este modificador de acesso restringe o acesso ao membro em que é utilizado para que seja acessado apenas pelas classes que herdam da classe que possui os membros com esse modificador de acesso e as classes que estão no mesmo pacote;
- `private`: este modificador de acesso é o modificador mais "restrito" do Java. Ele restringe o acesso dos membros que possuem esse modificador acesso apenas a própria classe e as classes que estão no mesmo pacote;

---

**set**

O termo *set* (**nesse caso**) diz respeito á métodos *setters*.

No Java existe o conceito de *encapsulamento*, que diz (de maneira simples) que seus atributos devem acessados exclusivamente por métodos se forem ser acessados fora da própria classe.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private String nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) { //método "setter"
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

---

O que você (provavelmente) está querendo fazer é um método *setter* privado:

```
private void setNota(double nota) {
    estud.notas[0] = nota;
}
```

Considerando os dois tópicos (o modificador de acesso `private` e o método *setter*), cabe a você decidir se quer realmente fazer isso.
Eu, particularmente, acho bobagem acessar um membro da sua própria classe através de um método *setter*.

Se você fosse "settar" o valor de `estud.notas[0]` através de outra classe, aí sim seria vantagem/correto utilizar um *setter* para isso e precisaria também verificar o modificador de acesso correto para o cenário.

Comment: Como especifiquei, quando uso em método publico consigo usar o primeiro código com o Scanner tranquilamente, agora usando o método private não sei como atribuir a posição da memória do array e nem como inserir a variável do Scanner na sintaxe do set

Comment: Especificou? A única chamada de método presente no código é a `nextDouble()` ._. Não encontrei nenhum _setter_ muito menos público. @crackeralphazer0

Comment: Man vocês estão viajando. O Scanner recebe o valor digitado pelo usuário, no primeiro exemplo utilizando o método publico consegui atribuir o valor do array no endereço [0], pelo Scanner normalmente. Já quando mudamos para privado não sei a sintaxe que indicaria na memoria [0] do array notas em que o scanner inNotas1 iria atribuir o valor. Não tem nada ha ver com o que existe no resto do código, quero apena saber qual seria a construção do código na ultima linha sendo o método privado

Comment: @crackeralphazer0 acredito que a resposta que postei tem o que você quer. Basta você incluir a declaração do método `private void setNota(double nota) { estud.notas[0] = nota; }` e chamá-lo assim: `setNota(inNota1.nextDouble());`. Por favor, diga-me se é isso o que quer.

Comment: Não funcionou mas mesmo assim obrigado

Comment: Mas é isso o que você quer? @crackeralphazer0  O que não funcionou? Deu algum erro?

Comment: Sim deu erro. Criei uma classe com um array de 3 posições para notas, sendo privado; Pretendo receber os valores das notas pelo Scanner, como disse acima o método sendo publico funcionou o código descrito primeiro. Já quando o método é privado a sintaxe muda, não estou conseguindo descobrir uma forma de que isso funcione em modo privado